# Search characters in a String and replace it with a blank space T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with a list of invalid characters like:

```
InVCh
-----

!
"
$
%
&
'
(
)
*
+
,
.
/
```

Then, i have a lot of tables with different number of columns (all of those columns are string type), example:

```
Product          Store
-------          ------
Prod1            Store1
Pr$od!2          Sto$re!2
P:;()ro!!!"d3    S:;()to!!!"re3
```

I would like to create a procedure that finds all those invalid characters and replace them with a blank space, if there are too many blank space together then i have to replace them with a single one space. So my expected result should be:

```
Product          Store
-------          ------
Prod1            Store1
Pr od 2          Sto re 2
P ro d3          S to re3
```

This is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. use a `while loop` to find and replace.

Comment: A `WHILE` loop would be very slow, @Squirrel

Comment: what do you recommend ?

Comment: While loop is slow... we need to consider million of records for each table...

Comment: Thinking `TRANSLATE`, @Squirrel. Writing something at the moment.

Comment: Translate is good but i have sql server 2016 and the function is not available.....

Comment: @GiuseppeLolli you should mention that in the question and tags.

Comment: @GiuseppeLolli if SQLCLR is an option you could create a SQLCLR function that allows regex replacements. Typically a regex is *far* faster than string manipulation. The problem with regex is that someone could write a bad one that gets into an infinite loop. The `Regex` class even has a timeout property! The other possible issue is that a regex has to read the entire string before it returns. This can be a problem when searching but not an issue here, where you *do* want to work on the entire string

Comment: @GiuseppeLolli maybe-not-so-irrational choice - use a regex in R.  [SQL Server 2016 Regular Expressions with the R Language](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4748/sql-server-2016-regular-expressions-with-the-r-language/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's SQL Server 2016, using [R is an option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/quickstart-r-run-using-tsql?view=sql-server-2017). This doesn't seem to be so far-fetched, as there's an MSSQLTips article from *2017* that describes this: [SQL Server 2016 Regular Expressions with the R Language](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4748/sql-server-2016-regular-expressions-with-the-r-language/).

The article's code isn't that hard either :

```
create table dbo.tblRegEx (id int identity, a varchar(300), b  varchar(300) );

-- 3. Remove duplicate words
exec sp_execute_external_script @language=N'R'
, @script = N'
pattern <-"\\b(\\w+\\s*)(\\1\\s*)+";
inData$a <- gsub(pattern, "\\1", inData$a, perl = T );
outData <- inData;'
, @input_data_1 = N'select id, a, b from dbo.tblRegEx'
, @input_data_1_name = N'inData'
, @output_data_1_name=N'outData'
with result sets ( as object dbo.tblRegEx);
```

This question asks for something far easier, just replace some characters.

```
create table #products 
(
    id int primary key identity, 
    product varchar(300), 
    store  varchar(300) 
);
go

insert into #products (product,store)
values 
('Prod1',            'Store1'),
('Pr$od!2',          'Sto$re!2'),
('P:;()ro!!!"d3',    'S:;()to!!!"re3')

exec sp_execute_external_script @language=N'R'
, @script = N'
pattern <-"[!\"$%&''()*+,./:;]+";
inData$product <- gsub(pattern, " ", inData$product, perl = T );
inData$store <- gsub(pattern, " ", inData$store, perl = T );
outData <- inData;'
, @input_data_1 = N'select id, product, store from #products'
, @input_data_1_name = N'inData'
, @output_data_1_name=N'outData'
with result sets ( as object #products);
```

Like all stored procedures, the results can only be returned to the client, or used as the source for an `INSERT INTO`. This could be to a stating or temporary table or a table variable that can be used to update the source table :

```
declare @outData table (id int primary key, product varchar(300), store  varchar(300) );

insert into @outData
exec sp_execute_external_script @language=N'R'
, @script = N'
pattern <-"[!\"$%&''()*+,./:;]+";   
inData$product <- gsub(pattern, " ", inData$product, perl = T );
inData$store <- gsub(pattern, " ", inData$store, perl = T );
outData <- inData;'
, @input_data_1 = N'select id, product, store from #products'
, @input_data_1_name = N'inData'
, @output_data_1_name=N'outData' 



update #products
set product = r.product,
    store   = r.store
from #products inner join @outdata r on r.id=#products.id

select * from #products
```

This returns :

```
id  product   store
--  -------   --------
1   Prod1     Store1
2   Pr od 2   Sto re 2
3   P ro d3   S to re3
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but i think is better insert all data into a temp table, then truncate target table and then re-insert all records to avoid an update of million of records in one table. Thanks!

Comment: @GiuseppeLolli a table variable is essentially a temp table in all versions prior to 2019. If you have that many rows, a better solution would be to use a permanent staging table identical to the target one and use [partition switching](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/08/24/reloading-fact-tables-with-zero-downtime/) to "replace" one table with another. This is a metadata operation so it's almost instantaneous.

Answer (score -1):

Without the version, I'm assuming you have access to the latest tools. Therefore you could use `FOR XML PATH` to create a string on characters that need replacing, and then `TRANSLATE` to get rid of them all:

```
WITH C AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('!'),
                ('"'),
                ('$'),
                ('%'),
                ('&'),
                (''''),
                ('('),
                (')'),
                ('*'),
                ('+'),
                (','),
                ('.'),
                ('/'))V(InVCh)),
PS AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('Prod1','Store1'),
                ('Pr$od!2','Sto$re!2'),
                ('P:;()ro!!!"d3','S:;()to!!!"re3')) V(Product,Store))
SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE(PS.Product,V.C,REPLICATE(LEFT(V.C,1),LEN(V.C))),LEFT(V.C,1),'') AS Product,
        REPLACE(TRANSLATE(PS.Store,V.C,REPLICATE(LEFT(V.C,1),LEN(V.C))),LEFT(V.C,1),'') AS Store
FROM PS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES((SELECT '' + InVCh
                          FROM C
                          FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(MAX)')))V(C);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dc4aa4e4c6f310aebf559782dff88c26)

Note that the the return value for the 3rd row is `'P:;rod3'` and `'S:;tore3'`, as neither semicolon (`;`) or colon(`:`) are in your list of characters to be removed. YOu'll need to add all the characters you need replacing.

Seems to OP has mentioned, in the comments, that they are using 2016 (why knowing what version you are using is important!). Using [`Ngrams8K`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) you could do this (looks messy though):

```
WITH C AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('!'),
                ('"'),
                ('$'),
                ('%'),
                ('&'),
                (''''),
                ('('),
                (')'),
                ('*'),
                ('+'),
                (','),
                ('.'),
                ('/'))V(InVCh)),
PS AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'Prod1','Store1'),
                (2,'Pr$od!2','Sto$re!2'),
                (3,'P:;()ro!!!"d3','S:;()to!!!"re3')) V(ID,Product,Store))
SELECT PS.Product,V.Product,
       PS.Store,V.Store
FROM PS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES((SELECT '' + N.token
                          FROM dbo.NGrams8k(PS.Product,1) N
                          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                            FROM C
                                            WHERE C.InVCh = N.token)
                          ORDER BY position
                          FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(8000)'),
                         (SELECT '' + N.token
                          FROM dbo.NGrams8k(PS.Store,1) N
                          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                            FROM C
                                            WHERE C.InVCh = N.token)
                          ORDER BY position
                          FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(8000)')))V(Product,Store)
```

Comment: Would be interesting to hear why this was downvoted.